# Enter Perforce Commands in p4v GUI

Tags: version-control, perforce, p4v

Is there a way to manually enter perforce commands in the p4v GUI?

I'm relatively new to Perforce and find the GUI useful for most of what I need to do, but I can see situations where a one line command would be much easier than navigating through the GUI.

Example:

Opening a file for edit that is nested deep in the source tree; this takes many clicks when done in the GUI but would be a relatively short command with environment variables set for my most commonly used directories.

```
p4 edit -c NNNNNN $DIRECTORY/file
```

It would be great if the command entered was also added to the Log window. I really like being able to scroll through the Log to see everything I've done in a session.

Comment: Why not just use the command line client ?

Comment: @gareth_bowles - I like p4v for a lot of tasks, for example viewing pending/submitted change lists for other users, so I would prefer to stick to the GUI. I'd really just like command line ability for tasks that involve a lot of hunting in the source tree.

Comment: I think what Gareth Bowles was suggesting was that you can generally use the GUI, but then just open a separate command line window for those occasional command line tasks you wish to perform. I jump back and forth between P4V and the command line all the time. I do see your point about using P4V's log window as a unified history, though.

Comment: @BryanPendleton - I agree that this would work, I was just really hoping for the unified history. I have to use several different perforce servers at the same time, so achieving an easily traceable history with a separate GUI and terminal means I'll need a separate terminal for each server. I use tmux, so it's manageable, just not optimal. My hope was that there was some view option or tool window that I was missing.

Comment: You're not alone in wanting this; it's one of the most popular ideas on the Perforce idea gathering site: http://www.p4ideax.com

Comment: @Matt Thanks for the link, I didn't know they had an idea gathering site. Unfortunately for me I'm stuck using an older version that is compatible with our systems. This will be a good method of getting an idea of whether or not a feature exists in the future though.

Comment: You *could* create a custom tool that simply runs whatever you feed it as a command.  It's kind of a dirty hack, though.  http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4v/custom_tools.html has details on how to set those up.

Answer (score 4):

The closest that exists right now is "File"->"Open Command Window Here" when you have a file selected in the file browsing pane. It will open a command line in that file's directory with all of the relevant environment set up.

Unfortunately, this won't give you unified Log, and you'll have to juggle a second window.